# Discord.py 2.0.0 :discord.errors.ClientException: This client already has an associated command tree

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am new to Discord.py and when i tries to add a slash command to my discord bot, I encountered the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\programs\bot.py", line 5, in <module>
    tree = app_commands.CommandTree(bot)
  File "C:\Users\trnt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ClientException('This client already has an associated command tree.')
discord.errors.ClientException: This client already has an associated command tree.
```

Below is my code:

```py
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
bot = Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(bot)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot Name: {bot.user}')
    for server in bot.guilds:
        await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=server.id))

@tree.command(name="test", description="Test to see if slash commands are working")
async def test(interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Test")

bot.run('My Token')
```

I am using Discord.py 2.0.0 and Python 3.10.11

Can someone tell me where I did wrong? I have searched questions on stackoverflow but none of them worked for me. Help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`commands.Bot` already has a command tree, there's no need for you to define it again.

```py
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot Name: {bot.user}')
    for server in bot.guilds:
        await bot.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=server.id))

@bot.tree.command(name="test", description="Test to see if slash commands are working")
async def test(interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Test")

bot.run('My Token')
```

Comment: Where is `tree` coming from in this code in the decorator?

Comment: sorry it was supposed to be bot.tree @JJCheung